# react router - pass props via url arguments

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-redux

I am developing a multilingual and multi-currency app that uses `react-router`, `react-router-redux` & `react-router-bootstrap` for routing.

Currently users arrive at the app with a default language and currency however I'd like to be able to provide some arguments in the url to set either the language or currency - something along the lines of `http://myapp.com/page1?lang='fr'`

I'd also like to have the ability to use these arguments on any page, so that:

`http://myapp.com/page1?lang='fr'` and `http://myapp.com/page2/example1/test?lang='ru'` are both handled the same way. Basically I want the router to check for the presence of these arguments in any url that is passed to it, and if they are present execute a function.

I can't find any clear information about this in the documentation for `react-router` but I'm sure it's possible. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the query params via 
`this.props.location.query.langs`  from inside the component also mentioned by **@Lucas**.

I have provided a working example for better understanding.

Apart from that In your scenario I will suggest you to look into `onEnter` hooks available in react router.

```js
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;
let Link = ReactRouter.Link;

function redirectBasedOnLang(nextState, replace) {
    // check nextState.location.query
    // and perform redirection or any thing else via
    console.log("called");
    console.log(nextState.location.query);
}

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  return (
    <b className="tag">{"Dashboard"}</b>
  );
}

FrDashboard

const FrDashboard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div> 
         <h3> Dashboard </h3>
         <hr/>
        Primary language: {props.location.query.lang}
    </div>
  );
}
 
class App extends React.Component {
   
   render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <h2>App</h2>

        {/* add some links */}
        <ul>
      <li><Link to={{ pathname: '/dashboard', query: { lang: 'fr' } }} activeClassName="active">Dashboard</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
     )
   }   
};

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={redirectBasedOnLang} />
          <Route path="dashboardfr" component={FrDashboard} />
    </Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.0/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>


<div id="test"></div>
```

```js
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let RouterContext = Router.RouterContext;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;

const Link = (props) => {
  return (
    <b className="lang" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.lang)}>{props.lang}</b>
  );
}
      
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.handleLang = this.handleLang.bind(this);
    this.state = { langs: [] };
  }
  
  handleLang(lang) {
    let langs = [].concat(this.state.langs);
    if(langs.indexOf(lang) != -1) {
      langs = langs.filter(item => item != lang);
    }
    else langs.push(lang);
    
    this.setState({langs: langs});
    
    this.context.router.push({
      pathname: '/',
      query: { langs: langs }
    });
  }
  
   render() {

     return (
      <div>
         <Link onClick={this.handleLang} lang={"fr "} />
         <Link onClick={this.handleLang} lang={"en "} />
         <Link onClick={this.handleLang} lang={"hi "} />
         
         <div>
           <hr/>
           <br/>
           active languague :
           <div>{this.props.location.query.langs ? [].concat(this.props.location.query.langs).join(',') : ''}</div>
         </div>
      </div>
     )
   }   
};

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} /> 
  </Router>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

```css
.lang {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width : 50px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.0/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, extremely comprehensive answer. I'm now accessing the `query` parameter and handling it successfully. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the [`location`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#location) prop passed by `react-router` to the component. You can see that it has a [`query` property](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#query). In that way you can simply access `this.props.location.query.lang` and you'll get the value that's in your query string.

You can check [this example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/query-params) in react-router project.

Comment: that link to the example is a 404